# How to efficiently calculate probabilities of not getting two pair?

Tags: probability, poker

Suppose two guys are playing 2 card draw poker. I am trying to find the probability of neither players drawing a pair.

Let $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$ denote the cards drawn.

We know that any card will do for the first card. We also can see

$$\Bbb P(C_1\sim C_2) = \frac{3}{51}= \frac{1}{17}$$

For the first player's second card ($C_3$), I set up the problem as

$$\Bbb P (C_ 3\sim C_ 1) = \Bbb P (C_3\sim C_1|C_2\sim C_1) \Bbb P (C_2 \sim C_1)+  \Bbb P (C_3\sim C_1|C_2\nsim C_1) \Bbb P (C_2 \nsim C_1) $$
$$\Bbb P (C_ 3\sim C_ 1) = \frac{3}{51} \frac{2}{50} + \frac{48}{51}\frac{3}{50}= \frac{1}{17}$$

I did something similar for Player 2 and got the same number. So the likelihood of each player not drawing a pair is $\frac{16}{17}$ and multiplying together gives us $\frac{256}{289}$

Assuming I did it correctly, this felt very clumsy and was very tedious to write out. Does anyone know a faster way I can do this?

Comment: For the record, the opposite event of "both players draw a pair" is "at most one draws a pair", not *neither draws a pair*.  Also, player one getting a pair and player two getting a pair are *not* independent events.

Comment: And they are not independent because.....the occurrence of one pair doesn't exclude the occurrence of the other?

Comment: As I calculated below, $Pr(A)=Pr(B)=\frac{1}{17}$ but $Pr(A\cap B) = \frac{73}{20825}\neq\frac{1}{17}^2=Pr(A)Pr(B)$.  This acts as proof that the two are not independent.  It actually is *more* likely that if the first player gets a pair that the second player *also* gets a pair.  Its almost like "*there are fewer numbers available*" for the second player (though there are still the two remaining of the number the first player got).

Comment: Keep in mind that once you select cards for A, the chances for B to not get a pair changes. Your count should reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of ways of dealing four cards where order matters is $52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49$.

Let us instead count the number of ways that *at least one of the players gets a pair*.  To do this, we will approach via inclusion-exclusion.

For the first person to get a pair and for us to not care what the second person gets (a pair or not), pick the first card.  The second card must match the first.  The remaining two cards can be anything.  There are then $52\cdot 3\cdot 50\cdot 49$ number of ways that the first person can get a pair ignoring whether or not the second person also gets a pair.

Similarly, there will be $52\cdot 3\cdot 50\cdot 49$ number of ways that the second person can get a pair ignoring whether or not the first person also gets a pair by symmetry.

Now, the way that *both* players get a pair is either both players' numbers are different or the same.  $52\cdot 3\cdot 48\cdot 3$ number of ways for the first case and $52\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ for the second case.

Let $A$ be the event that the first player gets a pair, $B$ be the event that the second player gets a pair.  The number of ways that at least one player gets a pair is $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B| = 2\cdot 52\cdot 3\cdot 50\cdot 49 - 52\cdot 3\cdot 48\cdot 3-52\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 741624$

Dividing by the number of ways of dealing, we have the probability that *at least one* gets a pair is $\frac{741624}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49}=\frac{2377}{20825}\approx 0.114$

The probability then that *neither* player gets a pair is $1-\frac{741624}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49}\approx 0.886$

Comment: This is a nice way. I wanted to use that formula for $|A\cup B|$ but I couldn't figure out how to apply it. In particular, I didn't get how to calculate their intersection. Is that just the case where both have to happen? As in each gets a paid?

Comment: Hey, nice! We got the exact same answers using different methods!

Comment: Does order of dealing matter? Because I tried to incorporate they dealt alternating cards. Is that unnecessary? If so, why?

Comment: Order of dealing does not in fact matter, however it was convenient for me to describe it as such to ensure that I counted everything correctly out of habit.  So long as your sample space and your outcomes are described and counted in the same way, it wont matter.  For example, you could calculate odds of a four of a kind in a four-card draw poker as $\frac{13}{\binom{52}{4}}$ or you could calculate it as $\frac{13\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49}$.  You should find these are both equal after minor simplifications.

Comment: @StanShunpike As far as if it was dealt to player one then player two then player one again then player two again, note that this is in direct bijection with the scenario that it is dealt to player one twice and then player two twice.  In that sense order doesn't matter either.

Comment: @JMoravitz But consider this: suppose you and I play poker and I am dealt to first. I get the Ace of spades. That means you can't have it, so why wouldn't order matter?

Comment: @StanShunpike Because before the deal has begun, if I get the second and the fourth card from the deck, without knowing how the deck has been shuffled the chances of a particular hand are exactly the same as if I took the first and second card from the deck, or any other two cards from the deck.  Certainly, **after** having the ace of spades given to you, the odds have changed, but that is the difference between a conditional probability and a regular one.

Comment: The chance the ace of spades is the first card in the deck is exactly the same chance as it being the second card in the deck, etc...

Comment: I am confused. Shouldn't the union of A and B include their intersection? That's not what your formula says.

Comment: Or is that because A already includes $A \cap B$, so we have to subtract it so it isn't included twice. So does that mean $|A \cup B \cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C| -2|A\cap B \cap C|$

Comment: According to the principle of inclusion exclusion, if you do the size of A plus the size of B it is as though you did what is common to both of them twice, so you must subtract their intersection to compensate for the overcounting.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a complementary counting method. Let us count the ways either A or B (or both) gets a pair. There are $13 * \dbinom{4}{2} * \dbinom{50}{2} = 95500$ ways that A can get a pair. This is the same for B, by symmetry, so we simply multiply that result by $2.$ The number of ways that A and B both get a pair is just $13 * \dbinom{4}{2} * (12 * \dbinom{4}{2} + 1) = 5694.$ The total count is $2 * 95500 - 5694 = 185406.$ The total number of ways to deal the cards is just $\dbinom{52}{2} * \dbinom{50}{2} = 1624350.$ The successful ways is then $1624350 - 185406 = 1438944$ (we subtract because this is the complementary count). Our answer is $\frac{1438944}{1624350} = \frac{18448}{20825},$ which is approximately $88.6\%.$